# Выпадающий список с выбором города vue

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-cli

Нужно, чтобы по клику на кнопку с названием города, допустим, Москва. Выпадал список, вида как на скриншоте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ниже код:

```
    <select name='' id=''>
      <option :value='item.seo_name' v-for='item in region' :key='item.name'>{{ item.name }}</option>
    </select>
```

Вью:

```
<script>
 export default {
  props: {
   region: {
    type: Array,
    default: () => []
   }
  }
 };

</script>
```

К сожалению, `option` нельзя стилизовать, как мне решить данную проблему?
И в кнопку нужно передавать тот город, который был выбран из списка.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте вместо `option` другой тег с поддержкой `v-model` – `input[type='checkbox']`:

```
<label
    v-for="item in region"
    :key="item.name"
>
    <input v-model="selectedRegion" :value="item.name" type="checkbox">
    <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
</label>
```

Сами чекбоксы стилями можно скрыть, но при этом на них останется работать `v-model` и передаваться параметр из `value`. Сам город можно в `span` выводить. Собственно `selectedRegion` – это будет строка с выбранным городом.

Comment: Спасибо.
Но по какой-то причине, при клике на любой город, выбираются все (ставится чекбокс). upd: моя ошибка

Comment: value поставили?

Comment: Выделялись все чекбоксы по причине, что я добавил ```selectedRegion``` в пропсы. Но если этого не сделать, то в консоли ошибка вида: 
Property or method ```selectedRegion``` is not defined on the instance